# Save last run time in SnapLogic to use in pipeline

Tags: middleware, snaplogic

I have created a pipeline which queries out a database for new records, I do this using the Last Modified TimeStamp field. In my query I want to retrieve only records modified since the last time the pipeline was run.

How can I do this? I'm new to SnapLogic but I know I need to essentually store the runtime as some sort of savable variable which can be used within expressions in the pipeline itself. I also need to have a fallback incase the variable doesn't exist (i.e. when its the first time its been run).

Answer (score 0):

You can save the timestamp in a file in SLDB against the pipeline name.

So, when your pipeline starts, read the timestamp against the pipeline name from the file (you can put `0` by default if there is not an entry for it in the file) then do whatever processing you want to do. After successful execution of your processing, you can save the `pipe.startTime()` against the pipeline name in the above-mentioned file; you have to replace the previous entry in all subsequent executions.